# Subroutine threaded JIT x86 machine code segfaults on return from statically compiled function

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, x86-64

I'm trying to write a subroutine threaded bytecode interpreter (dynamically mapping bytecode operations to native call instructions at runtime). My test program for the translation process executes correctly when I manually return from the called functions (written in C) with `asm("ret")`, but segfaults on compiler generated returns.

I've worked with assembly before but mostly with 32 bit MIPS, so admittedly I'm still learning x86 as I go.

Here's my compiler information:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-cet=auto
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.1.0 (GCC)
```

And I'm compiling with:

```
gcc subroutine_threading.c -std=gnu99 -no-pie -g -Wall -Wextra -O0 -o subroutine_threading
```

I've walked through the code with cgdb and the segfault occurs after entering my dynamically generated subroutine, which the debugger can't step through.

Additionally I've looked through the disassembly of the generated executable and it the main difference is the presence or absence of my manually inserted `ret` in `greet` between the two versions. I'll include both disassembled versions of the function below.

A potential cause for a segfault in the generated code would be an issue in one of my `call rel32` instructions, however, as seen below, the first call is successful and the error only occurs after the call to `puts` at the end of `greet`. Additionally, between compiling with `-no-pie` and the use of `MAP_32BIT` in `mmap` my jumps should always be within 2GB of each other. So I believe this is unlikely.

I suspect the issue is that when it tries to return after `pop %rbp` in `greet`, the return address is invalidated, but I'm not entirely certain. I've read a little about calling conventions for my setup but I'm not certain what I'm doing incorrectly if that's the issue as my dynamically generated subroutine takes no arguments and returns no value.

Here's the source code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#ifdef C_RETURN
    #define RETURN return
#else
    #define RETURN asm("ret")
#endif

void greet(void) {
    puts("Hello, World!");
    RETURN;
}

void dismiss(void) {
    puts("Goodbye, World!");
    RETURN;
}

void (*jump_table[])(void) = {
    greet, dismiss
};

const size_t SIZE = 1024;

void make_subroutine(unsigned char* code, int* bytecode, size_t length, void** jump_table) {
    int32_t offset;
    unsigned char* original = code;

    // push %rbp
    *code++ = 0x55; //?

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // call
        *code++ = 0xe8;
        // relative addr of function
        offset  = -((int32_t) (code - (unsigned char*) jump_table[bytecode[i]]));
        memcpy(code, &offset, sizeof offset);
        code += 4;
    }

    // pop %rbp
    *code++ = 0x5d; //?
    // ret
    *code++ = 0xc3;

    // dump generated machine code to file for inspection
    FILE* dump = fopen("dump.out", "wb");
    fwrite(original, sizeof (unsigned char), code - original, dump);
    fclose(dump);
}

void run_subroutine(void) {

    void* m = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_32BIT, -1, 0);
    assert(m);

    int bytecode[] = {0, 0, 0, 1};

    make_subroutine(m, bytecode, sizeof bytecode/sizeof (int), (void**) jump_table);

    void (*fn)(void) = m;
    fn();

    munmap(m, SIZE);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    run_subroutine();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the disassembly of the function giving me issues

With -DC_RETURN;

```
0000000000401196 <greet>:

void greet(void) {
  401196:   55                      push   %rbp
  401197:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    puts("Hello, World!");
  40119a:   48 8d 3d 67 0e 00 00    lea    0xe67(%rip),%rdi        # 402008 <_IO_stdin_used+0x8>
  4011a1:   e8 8a fe ff ff          callq  401030 <puts@plt>
    RETURN;
  4011a6:   90                      nop
}
  4011a7:   5d                      pop    %rbp ; probably fails here
  4011a8:   c3                      retq        ; or here
```

Without:

```
0000000000401196 <greet>:

void greet(void) {
  401196:   55                      push   %rbp
  401197:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    puts("Hello, World!");
  40119a:   48 8d 3d 67 0e 00 00    lea    0xe67(%rip),%rdi        # 402008 <_IO_stdin_used+0x8>
  4011a1:   e8 8a fe ff ff          callq  401030 <puts@plt>
    RETURN;
  4011a6:   c3                      retq   
}
  4011a7:   90                      nop
  4011a8:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4011a9:   c3                      retq
```

Also a formated hexdump of my dynamically generated code:

```
55          | push %rbp
e8 943145bf | call greet
e8 8f3145bf | call greet
e8 8a3145bf | call greet
e8 983145bf | call dismiss
5d          | pop %rbp
c3          | ret
```

The output of the program should be

```
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Goodbye, World!
```

However, when I compile with -DC_RETURN I get

```
Hello, World!
fish: “./subroutine_threading” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relative address for the call is taken from the *end* of the instruction, so your starting offset should not `code` but `code + sizeof(offset)`.  This will cause your `greet` function to start executing *after* the prolog, resulting in problems when you the `pop %ebp` and `ret` statements are executed.

Your `code += 4;` adjustment should be `code += sizeof(offset)`, and it is simplest to do this before the offset calculation (while saving the previous value for use in the `memcpy`).

Not related, but you can swap the operands of your `offset` calculation and get rid of the `-` to negate the result.

Comment: Beat me to it. As a general rule, the value of RIP is always the next instruction, so any instruction using RIP uses this value.